# D drive is read-only after windows 10 upgade

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, read-only

I'm trying to figure out why my D: drive is read only after updating to Windows 10. It is a separate hard drive and not a partition of another hard drive.

I do have bit locker installed but it is turned off and I never used it. I tried taking ownership, permissions, unchecking the read-only box, and more but still everything the folders become read-only again. I can open everything but just can't modify them.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue going from Win7 to Win10. Here's how I solved it (requires administrator rights):

1. **Right click** the conflicting folder (or disk), go to **Properties**, then to the **Security** tab, and click on **Advanced**.

   [image]
2. **Change the owner** so it becomes yours. You may want to check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" so its applied everywhere inside it.

   [image: screen shot]
3. Click **OK**, close the Properties dialog, and open it again.
4. From the Security tab, add your user to the permission list, allowing **Full control**. After applying the change you should have access to your files again.